# How to use artisan to make views in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, view, laravel-5.1

I have been looking in the docs for a solution to make views with basic CURD operations but without much success.

I guess this might be pretty simple, but am missing something or not looking hard enough.

i can make models and controllers using the below artisan commands

```
php artisan make:model modelName

php artisan make:controller controllerName
```

But how do we make the basic CURD views. something like

```
 php artisan make:views
```

cant find any doc for this. Please help

Comment: There is no artisan command to generate basic CRUD views, or even empty views for that matter.

Comment: is there any workaround to achieve this....

Comment: You could always write your own, it's pretty easy to [add new commands](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) to artisan

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the time of writing, there isn't a way to create views via artisan without writing your own command or using a third party package. You could write your own as already suggested or use [sven/artisan-view](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view).

Answer (score 12):

if you are using laravel 5.1 or 5.2 this gist can help you make:view command just create command copy and paste the code from gist.

Step 1:

`php artisan make:command MakeViewCommand`

Step 2:

copy class from this gist

https://gist.github.com/umefarooq/ebc617dbf88260db1448

Comment: if you do not need customizations is faster and easier than sven/artisan-view

Comment: Step 1 now returns `Command "make:console" is not defined.` You will need to use `make:command` instead.

Comment: which version of laravel you have tried, this was valid with 5.1 and 5.2 still i have used with 5.3 also.

Comment: How can I use that class to put content inside the created view?

Answer (score 6):

**Laravel officially doesn't have any Artisan cammands for views.**

But you could add third party plugins like **Artisan View**
Here's the link [Artisan View](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view)

After adding this plugin to your project by the guide provided [here](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view/blob/master/README.md) you should be able to perform following cammands :

- Create a view 'index.blade.php' in the default directory

  ```
  $ php artisan make:view index
  ```
- Create a view 'index.blade.php' in a subdirectory ('pages')

  ```
  $ php artisan make:view pages.index
  ```
- Create a view with a different file extension ('index.html')

  ```
  $ php artisan make:view index --extension=html
  ```

Comment: This is an easy way to do it.

Comment: this just creates a blank-empty file, which is pretty useless imho. Not similar to other frameworks which can create a proper working view-file, & show/populate data in the view file.

Answer (score 5):

There is very easy way to create a view(blade) file with `php artisan make:view {view-name}` command using **Laravel More Command** Package.

First Install Laravel More Command

> `composer require theanik/laravel-more-command --dev`

Then Run

> `php artisan make:view {view-name}`

For example

It create index.blade.php in **resource/views** directory

```
php artisan make:view index
```

It create index.blade.php in **resource/views/user** directory

```
php artisan make:view user/index
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In v5.4 you need to create the command with: 
**php artisan make:command MakeView**

and before you can use it, it must be registered in **App/Console/Kernel** like

```
protected $commands = [
        Commands\MakeView::class
    ];
```

then you make a view like: **php artisan make:view posts/create**

Answer (score 3):

To create a view (blade) file through command in laravel 8:

```
composer require theanik/laravel-more-command --dev

php artisan make:view abc.blade.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [sven/artisan-view](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view) package to make view from CMD, to install package write this command:

```bash
composer require sven/artisan-view --dev
```

After installing it, you can make a single view or folder with all views that contain {index-create-update-show}

To make a single file we using this command:

```bash
php artisan make:view  Name_of_view
```

For example

```bash
php artisan make:view index
```

To make a folder that contain all resources **index - create - update - show** write name of folder that contain all this files for example:

```bash
php artisan make:view Name_of_Folder -r
```

For example:

```
php artisan make:view blog -r
```

-r is a shorthand for --resource you can write full name or shorthand to make resource.

you can extend yields from master page  if master page inside in directory layouts we write command sith this format

```bash
php artisan make:view index --extends=layouts.master --with-yields
```

layouts is a directory this directory may be with a different name in your project the idea is name_of_folder/master_page that you want to extend yields from it.

For more [view docs](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view)