# How can I generate view from a Model in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, scaffolding

I want to generate View from an existing Model while creating a controller just like `MVC` in .NET framework using `entityframework`. I would really appreciate it if one can tell me a command to do what I want.
It would be something like:

```
php artisan make:controller MyController --view MyView
```

Comment: and what that command should do? generate blade files for you? create valid html/css/js code for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful package for creating view;

https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view

However, you can check this link too for further information:

[How to use artisan to make views in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935417/how-to-use-artisan-to-make-views-in-laravel-5-1#:~:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20writing,use%20sven%2Fartisan%2Dview).